# Combine CNN with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tflearn

I'm looking to implement a RNN along with a CNN in order to make a prediction based on two images instead of one alone with a CNN.
I'm trying to modify the alexnet model code:

```
def alexnet(width, height, lr, output=3):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, output, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=lr, name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_alexnet',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=0, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model
```

I have my images in a np array where each element is the pixel data for one image. I'm having trouble implementing the functionality of using two images with the RNN.

I've seen the reshape and lstm methods of tflearn which I believe should be placed before the final fully connected layer but not sure how to specify the number of images to use.

Also, would this be easier to implement with Keras?

Comment: What exactly do you want to analyze using rnn? What are the "timesteps" - encodings of images obtained via cnn or what?

Comment: @IvanK. I have a series of gameplay images in a np array. With RNN I want analyze motion between say X number of frames. I'm only using the CNN to extract the features of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to do the following. Let `model` be the network taking series of images as input and returning the predictions. Using finctional API, this schematically looks as follows:

```
    def create_model():
        input_data = keras.Input(shape=(number-of-images,shape-of-images))
        ### processing part ###
        model = keras.Model(input_images, your-predictions)
        return model
    model = create_model()
```

In the `processing part` you want to obtain encoding for each of the images and then analyze them as a sequence using RNN.

As the first step, you need to obtain encoding for all of the images. Let `encoder` be the network making encodings for individual images, returning `enc_dim`-dimensional encodings. To obtains encodings for all images efficiently, note that during training the `model` processes data with the shape `(batch-size,number-of-images,shape-of-images)`. Thus, in total you have `total-number-of-images`=*(batch-size) x (number-of-images)* of images. To process them, reshape the `input_data` to have dimension *(total-number-of-images,shape-of-images)* as follows:

```
    input_data_reshaped = tf.reshape(input_data, (-1,shape-of-images)),
```

and pass them through the `encoder`:

```
    image_encodings_flatterned = encoder(input_data_reshaped).
```

This will produce the output of the form *(total-number-of-images,enc_dim)*. To process the encodings, you need to restore *batch-size* dimension. This can be is easily done:

```
    image_encodings = tf.reshape(image_encodings_flatterned, (-1,number-of-images,enc_dim))
```

As expected, it will reshape the data to *(batch-size,number-of-images,enc_dim)*. This data can be readily processed by RNN layer or combination thereof. For example, for a single LSTM layer,

```
    rnn_analyzer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(parameters)
```

the predictions can be obtained as follows:

```
    rnn_encodings = rnn_analyzer(image_encodings).
```

`rnn_encodings` can be further used by dense layers to make final predictions.

By placing the above in the `processing part` of the `model`, you will reach the goal.

Comment: Is CNN still needed in this method in order to extract the features from the images?

Comment: Yes, the `encoder` is your CNN features extractor.